# Laravel 5.8 Likes system with AJAX Post Request Not Working

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I am building a Like system for my recipe application in Laravel and I am not able to get my AJAX POST request to function. It just simply isn't hitting my controller, so I am not able to store any likes. 
I have a relationship between three models, Like, User, Recipe. 
I have an individual likes table in my DB. The code is the following:

**My Models**
Like

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Like extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'likes';


    // Get all of the recipes that are assigned this like
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function recipes(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Recipe');
    }
}
```

User

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'username', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function recipes(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Recipe');
    }

    public function likes(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Like');
    }
}
```

Recipe

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Recipe extends Model
{
    //Table Name
    protected $table = 'recipes';
    // Primary Key
    public $primaryKey = 'id';
    // Timestamps
    public $timestamps = true;

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function category(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
    }

    public function comments(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment'); 
    }

    public function likes(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Like');
    }
}
```

AJAX

```
$.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

// Likes AJAX
var recipeId = 0;

$('.like').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var isLike = event.target.previousElementSibling == null;
    recipeId = event.target.parentNode.parentNode.dataset['recipeid'];

    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: urlLike,
        data: {isLike: isLike, recipeId: recipeId},
        success: function(data){
            console.dir(data);
            }
    })
        .done(function() {
            event.target.innerText = isLike ? event.target.innerText == 'Like' ? 'You like this post' : 'Like' : event.target.innerText == 'Dislike' ? 'You don\'t like this post' : 'Dislike';
            if (isLike) {
                event.target.nextElementSibling.innerText = 'Dislike';
            } else {
                event.target.previousElementSibling.innerText = 'Like';
            }
        });
});
```

Controller Method

```
 public function likeRecipe(Request $request){

        $recipe_id = $request['recipeId'];
        $is_like = $request['isLike'] === 'true';
        $update = false;
        $recipe = Recipe::find($recipe_id);
        if (!$recipe) {
            return null;
        }
        $user = Auth::user();
        $like = $user->likes()->where('recipe_id', $recipe_id)->first();
        if ($like) {
            $already_like = $like->like;
            $update = true;
            if ($already_like == $is_like) {
                $like->delete();
                return null;
            }
        } else {
            $like = new Like();
        }
        $like->like = $is_like;
        $like->user_id = $user->id;
        $like->recipe_id = $recipe->id;
        if ($update) {
            $like->update();
        } else {
            $like->save();
        }
        return null;
}
```

I'm getting various HTTP errors thrown at me as I mess with the AJAX file, but it is never working. Please help! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please comment what errors you're having.
HTTP codes?

Comment: I'm having 405 and 500 errors. Thank you! @FernandoLeón

Comment: I am also getting an alert with undefined from: success: function(data){
            console.dir(data);
            }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this kind of situation. You need learn how to debug properly for ajax request. There are thousand reason for return 500 error.

1st step: make sure your ajax function hit your url properly. Make a simple method and `dd()` something.

```
public function likeRecipe(Request $request){
     dd('Yes! it working !');
}
```

Go to your browser right click and Inspect then go to Network tab then you can see your request. Click on your request then look for response tab.There you can find exactly what happened.

Comment: Thank you! I used this technique, spent some time on it and figured out the errors! Much appreciated!

Comment: I am glad that my technique help you. You can accept my answer if it helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

405 means your likeRecipe function not running at all and 500 means there is any response error so try remove some of your code from likeRecipe function try again for example your first try could be:

```
public function likeRecipe(Request $request){
return null;
}
```